# Why did Alexander Randall want Mary Hawkins to marry Jonathan Randall?

Tags: outlander-universe

In *Dragonfly in Amber*, Alexander Randall's dying wish was for Mary Hawkins to marry his brother Jonathan so their child would be a legitimate Hawkins. Why didn't Alexander marry Mary himself, which would have accomplished the same goal, albeit leaving her a widow? They would have had to find someone to perform the ceremony, but that shouldn't have been difficult. Jonathan was willing to provide for Mary and the child in either case.

(I understand that the marriage made the genealogy work out, but I am looking for an in-world reason.)

Answer (score 2):

I think the simple answer is that it would be scandalous.  Alex did not think he should marry Mary because he had nothing to offer her and knew he was dying. Although Alex was a gentleman, that did not stop the unplanned sex from occurring. The emotions got better of him.  This is a common theme in the series where emotions override what is right and emotions often are praised as more right then right.

such as:

- Claire deciding to go back to Frank or stay with Jamie
- Poisoning Prince Charles
- Jamie's duel with Jonathan

Once the deed was done, it was too late to fix it.
Basically, the right thing to do was not touch Mary and let her go.  However, their emotions made them forget what was right.

Answer (score 1):

It was more than just "legitimizing" the child, i.e., giving the child the Randall name. If Mary had married Alexander, then she would have been immediately widowed, and since Alex was destitute, there would be nothing for her to inherit. However, Jonathan had more social standing as an officer in His Majesty's Dragoons, and should he die in battle, his army pension would provide some measure of support for Mary and the child.